# iOS Swift: Firebase Dynamic Links: Short URL not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using deeplink in my iOS app

customAppScheme://openID#ID=12345

This says to open a particular item page.

I want to use the same as part of the dynamic link.

With the custom URL generator

Long URL:  `https://<myCode>.app.goo.gl/?ibi=com%2Ecompany%2EmyAPP&ius=customAppScheme%3A%2F%2FopenID%23ID%3D12345&isi=1234567890&imv=1%2E0&ifl=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle%2Ecom&link=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle%2Ecom`

Absolute URL: `https://<myCode>.app.goo.gl/?ibi=com.company.myAPP&ius=customAppScheme://openID#ID=12345&isi=1234567890&imv=1.0&ifl=https://google.com&link=https://google.com`

Short URL: `https://<myCode>.app.goo.gl/aHS1Vq5RZYL6kGR02`

Link: https://google.com

build ID: "com.company.myAPP"

customScheme: "customAppScheme://openID#ID=12345"

If I use the long URL, it works properly. (I add the link in notes and click the link.)
The app opens and goes to the given item page.

But when I use the short URL, the app opens but after that nothing else. It doesn't go to the item page.

PFB my app delegate method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let dynamicLinks = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() else {
        return false
    }

    let handled = dynamicLinks.handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in

        if let dynamiclinkURL = userActivity.webpageURL, let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: dynamiclinkURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) {

            if let queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems {

                queryItems.forEach { queryItem in

                    if let value = queryItem.value, queryItem.name == "ius" {
                        handelLink(url: value)
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }


    return handled
}
```

This method works perfectly for the long url. But for short url this does not work.
Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong and missed something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am facing same issues for short link DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink not retrun link or error

Comment: Was this issue resolved? facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that short link has the same parameters as long link.
To compare links, navigate to debug page for each link. Append `d=1` parameter to the end of the link to get URL for debug page. For short link debug page is `https://<myCode>.app.goo.gl/aHS1Vq5RZYL6kGR02?d=1` , for long link `https://<myCode>.app.goo.gl/?ibi=com%2Ecompany%2EmyAPP&ius=customAppScheme%3A%2F%2FopenID%23ID%3D12345&isi=1234567890&imv=1%2E0&ifl=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle%2Ecom&link=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle%2Ecom&d=1`

Comment: Hello Oleksiy, I have already done the same and checked the link for both long and short URLs. Both have the same parameters

Comment: Please share both (short and long) links. Feel free to open Firebase support bug to share privately.

Comment: i am facing same issues for short link DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink not retrun link or error

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov i solve my issues in my case i don't enable Associated Domains capability for app